# Method Returning that Cookie Does Not Exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to access a cookie with HttpOnly, Secure, Domain of "localhost", Path of "/", SameSite of "None". My front end is running on port 3000 with backend running on port 7014. I have enabled CORS. LocalHost is current running with HTTPS in a dev environment.

Whether I do "deleteValue" or "getValue", I am consistently met with "Cookie does not exist" from one of my returns. I have checked the fetch payload and the "key" is being correctly set to the name of the cookie I am trying to access ("jwt" in this case). Is there something I am missing here?

```
[HttpPost("accessCookie", Name = "accessCookie")]
public IActionResult accessCookie([FromBody] CookieRequest cookieBase) {
    string cookieValue = "";

    string key = cookieBase.key ?? "";
    string actionRequest = cookieBase.actionRequest ?? "";

    if (actionRequest != "getValue" && actionRequest != "deleteValue") { 
        return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "actionRequest not of allowed values" });
    }

    try {
        if (actionRequest == "getValue") {  
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(key, out cookieValue))
            {
                return Ok(new { success = true, message = cookieValue });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Cookie does not exist" });
            }
        }

        if (actionRequest == "deleteValue" && HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(key, out cookieValue))
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
            return Ok(new { success = true, message = "Cookie removed" });
        }
        else {
            return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Cookie does not exist" });
        }
    } catch {
        return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Failed for unknown reason" });
    }

}
```

Class CookieRequest is built with the following :

```
public class CookieRequest
{
    public string? key { get; set; }
    public string? actionRequest { get; set; }
}


I am sending, via fetch request from ReactJS the following:

(async () => {
try {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_apiBaseURL + "/api/Helper/accessCookie", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "key": "jwt", "actionRequest": "getValue" })
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log("yay", result);
    } else {
        console.log("HTTP request failed with status", response.status);
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
})();
```

No errors are printed, just that the response is "success: false, message: "Cookie does not exist""

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My ReactJS script did not include the "credentials: 'include'" attribute. The corrected code is:

```
(async () => {
try {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_apiBaseURL + "/api/Helper/accessCookie", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "key": "jwt", "actionRequest": "getValue" }),
credentials: "include"
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log("yay", result);
    } else {
        console.log("HTTP request failed with status", response.status);
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
})();
```